# Insert SubView in TableView's Rows

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have made my UI through C# and not using xcode.
I have added a UITableview to my view(mainscreen) and want to insert a subview to each cell of the table.
The issue is i cant access the rows individually?
How do i fetch the row index number and add a subview to that row?

Comment: Are you implementing  `UITableViewSource`, how did you layout your table view?

Comment: i would like to know more about layouts....trying to search for something similar to flow layout but cant find have you implemented it?if i can get a flow layout then i will add the subview directly to the layout and it will auto arrange...

Comment: iOS doesn't have anything like a "flow layout". If you really need it, I would subclass `UIView` and override `LayoutSubviews` to position each child view. Honestly I think you would be better off picking a design that matches iOS more closely, however.

Comment: Frankly speaking i need something in which i can generate subview one after another and get auto-arrange so anything that can help me do that would be great any suggestions??....both in xcode and in C# is cool....

Comment: Show us some code, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollectionView and custom cell subviews.  Closest thing to flow layout if done correctly.

Or return custom UITableViewCell cells for the CellForRowAtIndexPath delegate calls.
(C# is GetCell() on tableview datasources)

You need to experiment with designing the views in xcode, and learning about springs and struts or auto layout tactics used in iOS.